# What is the actual usage of "If I would" and "If I could"?

Tags: word-choice

What is the actual usage of "If I would" and "if I could"?

For example:

> "If I could reach the end of the sky,..."

or

> "If I would reach the end of the sky,..."

which one sounds better?

Comment: "*If I would reach the end of the sky,...*" doesn't mean what you think it means.  To express that thought in English we would say, "*If I were to reach the end of the sky...*" or, "*If I reached the end of the sky...*"

Comment: *Would* in the *if* part is an unusual pattern not for general use. It indicates a request or volition, like "If you would please wash your hands, then we can eat.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have quite different meanings.

*Could* is a close relation of *can*. But *would* is a relative of *will*. So *could* involves an expression of ability, whilst *would* one of willingness.

> If I **could** run as fast as Usain Bolt I would compete in the Olympic games, but unfortunately I **can't**.
>
> If he **would** only look carefully he would find the missing item, but unfortunately he **will not**.